"The property or navigation cannot be added type because a property or navigation with the same name already exists" when adding migration
I am working on a .NET 8 project using C# and Entity Framework Core. I am trying to add a navigation property in my data model to create a connection in the tables. I followed the documentation from Microsoft and I added the properties in the data models accordingly for creating two way navigation. However, I am getting the following error when I run the command Add-Migration NewMigration

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The property or navigation 'UserAddressData' cannot be added to the 'UserData' type because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on the 'UserData' type.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here are my model classes:
public class UserData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public AddressData UserAddressData { get; set; }
}

public class AddressData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public UserData UserData { get; set; }
}

I also tried to add the configurations manually but I am still getting the same error.
I installed the Entity Framework Core packages and used an empty database. I tried adding the configurations manually from either side, but nothing worked. The migration run only if I delete the navigation property.
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserData> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("User");
    builder.Property(x => x.UserAddressData)
        .IsRequired(false);
    builder.HasOne(x => x.UserAddressData)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<AddressData>(x => x.UserData)
        .HasPrincipalKey<UserData>(x => x.UserAddressData);
}


What is the desired database structure? Which exact documentation have you followed?

Also see this answer

you have a mistake in configuration. Without specifying navigation prop for the relationship, EF assumes that you are used shadow navigation prop. That lead to create duplicated relationships. you can see the detailed in your migrations code.
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserData> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("User");
    builder.HasOne(x => x.UserAddressData)
        .WithOne(x => x.UserData)
        .HasForeignKey<AddressData>(x => x.Id)
        .IsRequired(false);
}


I tried this but unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue. I can't generate the migration file because of this error

You are correct. After rechecking, I foound that you have another mistake on configure foreign key and principal key. Please recheck my answer

I am still getting same error. I have veryfied also that the nuget packages that I have installed are correct but nothing is working. I will find another way to bind it

You should remove
builder.Property(x => x.UserAddressData)
        .IsRequired(false);

If you use Navigation property in builder.Property, it will autogenerate things and you will end up with this error.
